# Cold airplane window frame

Tags: temperature, aircraft

I was flying from Asia to Europe and noticed that the bottom of the window frame was ice cold while the top was warm. Why?

My theory: The sunlight warming the air between the "inner window" and the "actual window" causes the warm air to move up within the airplane hull. [image]

Comment: I will be surprised of such an appreciable gradient